# How to make the function only runs once JS

Tags: javascript, events

How to make the function only runs once per button?
if clicks in "click me" only works once, and the same for the other buttons.
Order not to put much code, I put an example..:
http://jsbin.com/apexod/2/edit

```
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="hello('Jhon')"><br>
<input type="button" value="click me1" onclick="hello('Gerard')"><br>
<input type="button" value="click me2" onclick="hello('Kaoru')">
<script>
function hello(id){
    alert("hello "+id);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Edit: nevermind, the answer is below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send the button element reference along to the function, and remove the event from the button:

```
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="hello(this,'Jhon')"><br>
<input type="button" value="click me1" onclick="hello(this,'Gerard')"><br>
<input type="button" value="click me2" onclick="hello(this,'Kaoru')">
<script>
function hello(el, id){
    alert("hello " + id);
    el.onclick = null;
}
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/CDjGY/

Answer (score 4):

A solution would be to register what buttons have been clicked :

```
<script>
var done = {}
function hello(id){
   if (done[id]) return;
   done[id] = 1; 
   alert("hello "+id);
}
</script>
```

(another one would be to use a utility lib like jQuery and its [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function but this would be overkill for just that)

Answer (score 1):

Once executed you can override the function with an empty function

```
function hello(){
     alert("hello " + id);
     hello = function(){}
}
```

Comment: That will make all buttons stop working once one button is clicked. It's possible that's what the OP meant (the question isn't completely clear about that), but the wording suggests that the buttons should work individually.